# Android Tabs and global variables

Tags: android, global-variables, android-tabs

I am using android TabWidget and I have one main activity where I am managing all the tabs.
Each tab has his own activity:

```
private void setTabs()
{
    addTab("News", NewsActivity.class);
    addTab("Project", ProjectActivity.class);
    addTab("About", AboutActivity.class);
    addTab("Contact", ContactActivity.class);
}
```

The data for each tab is downloaded from the server in JSON format. My goal is to download all the data on the oppening of the application and then to use it for each tab (activity).

Is there a possibility to share those variables from the main activity to the others where I am managing the tabs? I know about using the Intent class but may be there is another easier solution with the tabs.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare static variables in your main activity and store the data in them.

For example, `public static integer myInt;`

```
myInt = ...;
```

Now when you go to the other Activities, just use **`MainActivity.myInt`** to access its value and even update it if you want. No need to pass the variable around using intents.

Comment: Thank you swayam, is there a posibility that android system will kill those static variables after some time or not?

Comment: Nopes! None at all! I use this method **EXTENSIVELY** in all my applications as I find it very tedious to send 10 values via intents and trust me, it works like a charm! :D

Comment: I realise that the other answers might be more logical and conventional way to do things, but this is merely a hack that I follow which makes coding easier for me. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a class that would hold any variables or objects that you might want to use throughout the whole app.

```
public class myClass {
    private static int myInt;
    public static void setMyInt(int i)
    {
        myInt = i;
    }

    public static int getMyInt()
    {
        return myInt;
    }

}
```

Then you can set any variable from anywhere and use it anywhere.

```
myClass.setMyInt(10);
int i = myClass.getMyInt();
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to create your `class MyAppication extends Application` (you will also have to add it into Manifest). This `MyApplication` class will exist all the time your app is running so you can store things in there.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I will try to do it and let you know if everything works fine. If you have an example of how to do it, it can be even better.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to use fragments for your purpose..

You have the main activity which has the tabhost/tabwidget and a layout to display a fragment for each..

Based on the currently selected tab you display the corresponding fragment in the layout.

This way your main activity can have whatever variables data your fragments need to use.

All the fragments are able to access the data in the activity they are displayed in, just make sure to create getters and setters